# How to understand "cat > file_name << blah" command?

Tags: bash, shell, here-document

In following command cat takes the content of here-doc and redirects it to file named conf:

```
cat > conf << EOF
var1="cat"
var2="dog"
var3="hamster"
EOF
```

How to understand the order of commands here? Does `bash` first processes everything else(here-doc part) and as a final step it looks the `> conf` part?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Here-Document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) is a kind of shell redirection, so the shell will perform it as normal redirection, from beginning to the end (or from left to right, or order of appearance). This's defined by POSIX:

> If more than one redirection operator is specified with a command, the
>   order of evaluation is from beginning to end.

---

In your command, `cat` will perform `> conf` first, open and truncate `conf` file for writing, then reading data from `Here-Document`.

Using `strace`, you can verify it:

```
$ strace -f -e trace=open,dup2 sh -c 'cat > conf << EOF
var1="cat"
var2="dog"
var3="hamster"
EOF
'
...
open("conf", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
...
```

Comment: I see. So basically what happens in case of `cat > file_name << blah` is that before executing `cat` the _stdout_ of shell is connected to file named `file_name` and then _stdin_ of shell is connected to _here-doc_?

Comment: @Martin: Yes. You can see `open` was called before `dup2`.

Answer (score 12):

Well, let's find out:

```sh
unset file
cat >"$file" <<EOF
this is not in ${file=./myfile}
EOF
```

---

```
bash: : No such file or directory
```

Dang. I guess it must be doing the `>"$file"` part first then. But what if...?

```sh
unset file
<<EOF cat >"$file"
this is in ${file=./myfile}
EOF
```

...no error...?

```
cat ./myfile
```

---

```
this is in ./myfile
```

As it appears, order matters.

Answer (score -1):

When `bash` creates the process to run `cat`, it opens `conf` for write on file descriptor 1 and opens a temporary file (for the here-document) for read on file descriptor 0, before `exec`ing the program.  In this case, it doesn't really matter in which order those actions happen.

Order does become significant when file descriptors are reassigned, e.g. with `2>&1`.