# "cat << limit_string > filename" vs "cat > filename << limit_string"

Tags: io-redirection, cat, here-document

When using [here documents](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to write multi-line messages to file, in bash, does it matter in which order we apply the here-document (`<<`) and output redirect (`>`) operators?

In other words, is there a difference between the following two approaches?

1. here-doc first

   ```
   cat << my_limit_string > my_file
   line 1
   line 2
   my_limit_string
   ```
2. output redirect first

   ```
   cat > my_file << my_limit_string
   line 1
   line 2
   my_limit_string
   ```

In this simple example it does not seem to make a difference, but I wonder if there are cases in which the wrong order would lead to unexpected results.

The [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) says:

> Note that the order of redirections is significant.

And the answers to [How to understand "cat > file_name << blah" command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213574) suggest the order could indeed matter.

Comment: the two are equivalent, difference is a matter of taste or  readablilty.

Comment: @Archemar: Thanks. I just found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213579) which suggests the order could matter in some cases. Would you agree?

Comment: In some cases. This is not one of those. For example, the order matters in `foo cat > my_file << my_limit_string > my_other_file` - each output redirection is applied in turn and the last one is the one that ultimately applies. For independent redirections the order doesn't matter

Comment: in case of multiple redirection, or self included/self erased/auto included files, ordr my matter. In case of unique redirection, without self inclusion, order doesn't matter.